# Problems using libpng in iPhone project

Tags: iphone, xcode, libpng

I am trying to add libpng to my iPhone project.

I copied the .c and .h files to their own directory "thirdparty/libpng/" and I included png.h in my texture class:

```
#ifndef PNG_H
    #include "thirdparty/libpng/png.h"
#endif
```

At this point my project compiles great with no warnings and errors.

Next I tried adding a function to check if a texture is a png, and I get a compile error on png_sig_cmp, even though png.h is included:

```
#define PNG_BYTES_TO_CHECK 4
int GETexture::CheckIfValidPNGTexture( const char* pTextureName, FILE **ppFp )
{
    char buf[PNG_BYTES_TO_CHECK];

    /* Open the prospective PNG file. */
    if ((*ppFp = fopen(pTextureName, "rb")) == NULL)
        return 0;

    /* Read in some of the signature bytes */
    if (fread(buf, 1, PNG_BYTES_TO_CHECK, *ppFp) != PNG_BYTES_TO_CHECK)
        return 0;

    /* Compare the first PNG_BYTES_TO_CHECK bytes of the signature.
     Return nonzero (true) if they match */

    return(!png_sig_cmp(buf, (png_size_t)0, PNG_BYTES_TO_CHECK)); // <- COMPILE ERROR

}
```

The error I get is: No matching function for call to 'png_sig_cmp'

The header is definitely getting included. If I try to type something random in it like "sdfdd" I get a compile error, showing it is parsing that header file.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

I had exactly the same problem once and what helped me was simple casting - because if you look into png.h header file , png_sig_cmp definition :

```
 png_sig_cmp(png_const_bytep sig, png_size_t start, png_size_t num_to_check)
```

First parameter is **png_const_bytep** - which is defined as :

```
PNG_CONST png_byte        FAR * png_const_bytep
```

which translated really as :

```
const unsigned char*
```

I would simple typecast :

```
return(!png_sig_cmp((png_const_bytep)buf, (png_size_t)0, PNG_BYTES_TO_CHECK));
```

Hope it helps!